# Placing ImageView on top of Camera Preview

Tags: android

So I have an xml layout im using and it has two main elements, a framelayout that houses a camera preview, and a imageview. The image view is supposed to be visible over the framelayout and it is until the camerapreview is turned on then it gets pushed behind it. What am i doing wrong?

I've done a lot of testing removing elements from the layout and rebuilding and i cant seem to fix the cause of the error, i believe the cause must be somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is supposed to get push behind it because is a `RelativeLayout`.  I think you should use a `LinearLayout`.  Also the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` is an invalid parameter in `RelativeLayout`.

You can try and force the image view to align top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="390dip" 
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip">        

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="305dip"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/try_3"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/previewframe1"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:layout_height="310dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How can i put them on top of each other if its a LinearLayout? Also it works when i don't turn on the Camera Preview, but once i turn it on it breaks. I did remove the weight though

Comment: Still nothing im sorry, I think the issue is related to the camera preview class or code

Comment: Hmm, well I don't know. The camera preview and the imageview should be one on top of another if you use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` no matter what.

Comment: For some reason the imageview gets pushed behind it

Comment: O I see what you are saying (I think). Then you should have the camera preview have a transparent background just like the imageview. Or change the order on the xml (look at edit).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14774/discussion-between-peter-and-0gravity)

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of the ImageView and/or the layout it is contained in to android:background="@null" please for transparency.